# Java: ERROR variable scopes in if statements

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, compiler-errors, switch-statement

**Problem:**

An internet service provide offers three different subscription packages:

Package 1: $15.95 a month for up to 10 hours of service.  Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.
Package 2: $20.95 a month for up to 20 hours of service.  Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.
Package 3: $30.99 per month unlimited access.

**Write a program which does the following:**

Ask the user which plan they have.

Ask the user for the month number (1-12) of which month they are being billed.

Ask the user how many hours they used.

Display the cost of their bill.

Also display how much money Package 1 customers would would have saved if they purchased packages 2 or 3, and how much money Package 2 customers would have saved if they purchased Package 3.

If there were no savings, do not display this message.

**Input Validation:**

The plan number cannot be negative.

The plan number must be a value [1, 3].

The number of hours cannot be negative.

The number of hours cannot exceed the total number of hours for a given month.

Months with 30 days have 720 hours, months with 31 days have 744 hours, February with 28 days has 672 hours (don't worry about leap years).

Validate that the user does not enter a value greater than the total hours for a given month.

**See the table below.**

**Months, Days, Hours.**

January, 31, 744.

February, 28, 672.

March, 31, 744.

April, 30, 720.

May, 31, 744.

June, 30, 720.

July, 31, 744.

August, 31, 744.

September, 30, 720.

October, 31, 744.

November, 30, 720.

December, 31, 744.

**My question.**

I am having problems with my variables. I know there is better ways to code this program, however you should have in mind that this is my fourth week coding in Java.

I used too much if statements, and when I try to compile it; I get 12 errors with some variables. I assume that the variable scope of the variables it is blocked by a if statement somewhere. Because the compiler is asking to initialize the variables even though they were initialized before.
Any help will be appreciated :)

```
/*
 * Homework 04 Problem 05
 * Student: Kevin Crespin
 * CIN: 
 * Description: This program does the following:
 * Ask the user which plan they have.
 * Ask the user for the month number (1-12) of which month they are being billed.
 * Ask the user how many hours they used.
 * Display the cost of their bill.
 * Also display how much money Package 1 customers would would have saved if they purchased
 * packages 2 or 3, and how much money Package 2 customers would have saved if they purchased
 * Package 3. If there were no savings, do not display this message.
 */
// import scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW04P05{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // USER MENU
    final String USER_MENU =
        " \n" +\
        "[1] Package 1: $15.95 a month for up to 10 hours of service. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.\n" +
        "[2] Package 2: $20.95 a month for up to 20 hours of service. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.\n" +
        "[3] Package 3: $30.99 per month unlimited access.\n" +
        " \n" +
        "Enter [1 - 3] for select your package: ";
    final int PACKAGE_1 = 1;
    final int PACKAGE_2 = 2;
    final int PACKAGE_3 = 3;
    System.out.print(USER_MENU);
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    if (choice < 0) {
        System.out.println("The menu choice cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 3]");
        System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (choice == 0) {
        System.out.println("The menu choice cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 3]");
        System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (choice > 3) {
        System.out.println("The menu choice must be a value [1 - 3]");
        System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.print("[1] January   [4] April  [7] July       [10] October\n");
    System.out.print("[2] February  [5] May    [8] August     [11] November\n");
    System.out.print("[3] March     [6] June   [9] September  [12] December\n");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter [1 - 12] for select billed month: ");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    if (month < 0) {
        System.out.println("The month cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 12]");
        System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (month == 0) {
    System.out.println("The month cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 12]");
    System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
    System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (month > 12) {
        System.out.println("The month must be a value [1 - 12]");
        System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    double hours;
    double savings_1;
    double savings_2;
    double total_1;
    double total_2;
    final double total_1d = 15.95;
    final double total_2d = 20.95;
    final double total_3d = 30.99;
    // USER MENU SWITCH
    switch (choice) {
        case PACKAGE_1:
            if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 744) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the month selected.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 744) {
                        total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (month == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 672) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on February.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 672) {
                        total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 720) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 722 on the month selected.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
            }
                else {
                    if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 720) {
                        total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
                    }
                }
            }
        case PACKAGE_2:
            if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
                if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 744) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the selected month.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 744) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
                    }
                }
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $20.95");
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1); 
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 744) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1);
                    }
                }

            else if (month == 2) {
                if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 672) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on February.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1){
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 672) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
                    }
                }
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $20.95");
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1); 
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 672) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 720) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 722 on the selected month.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
            }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1){
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 720) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
                    }
                }
                }
                else {
                    if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $20.95");
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1); 
                    }
                    else if (hours > 20 && hours <= 720) {
                        total_2 = (hours - 20) + 20.95;
                        System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
                        savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                        System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_1);
                    }
                }
            }
        case PACKAGE_3:
            if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
                if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours you used your plan package: ");
            hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 744) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
                }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
                    savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                    System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_2);
                }
            }
            else if (month == 2) {
                if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 672) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on February.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
                }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
                    savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                    System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_2);
                }
            }    
            else {
                if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
                hours = input.nextInt();
                if (hours > 720) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 720 on the selected month.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (hours < 0) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
                    System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
                }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
                    savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                    System.out.println("You could saved: $" + savings_2);
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Compiling the code produces this:

```
HW04P05.java:176: error: variable hours might not have been initialized
                                        if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                                            ^
HW04P05.java:178: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:184: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:214: error: variable hours might not have been initialized
                                        if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                                            ^
HW04P05.java:216: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:222: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:252: error: variable hours might not have been initialized
                                        if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1) {
                                            ^
HW04P05.java:254: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:260: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                                savings_1 = total_1 - total_2d;
                                                            ^
HW04P05.java:286: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                        savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                                                    ^
HW04P05.java:310: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                        savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                                                    ^
HW04P05.java:334: error: variable total_1 might not have been initialized
                                    savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
                                                ^
12 errors
```

Comment: in what line do you assign value to variable `hours`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov there are a few lines that assign a value to hours, but there are also some paths that have not.

Comment: At some point in your `else-if` statements you are using the variable/s without ever assigning it a value.

Comment: The value must be assigned by the user.

Comment: Also, did you mean to use exclusive-or `^` in your if statements, or did you really want to or `||` them?

Comment: You are asking the user to enter the hours in a number of places in the code. Is there a scenario where the user would not need to enter the hours? If not, then ask for the hours first, before you enter into all the logic statements.

Comment: You can initialize the variables with something the user cannot enter when you declare them... then you might even use that later on to know the user hasn't entered a correct value. At least initializing them will get rid of your compiler errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that some execution paths in your code do not set a value to `hours`. It is difficult to see this problem because you are mixing input validation with result calculation logic.

You could just initialize hours to 0, but I suspect that your program still won't work the way you expect.

While there are many ways to solve this problem, I would recommend breaking the code into a number of smaller parts to solve each problem individually. There are a number of advantages to this, including being able to test each piece separately, and making it easier to understand and, more importantly, maintain each piece.

If you separate each piece into it's own method, your main method could look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int plan = getPlanFromUser();
    int month = getMonthFromUser();
    int hours = getHoursFromUser(month);
    evaluateSavings(plan, month, hours);
}
```

Then to get the plan from the user, you write a method called getPlanFromUser() that retrieves the user's input and validates it before returning a valid selection.

Likewise with the other 'get' methods, with the special case being `getHoursFromUser()` where you pass the month so that the method can validate that the correct hours are entered.

Finally, your `evaluateSavings()` method receives all the users input (which has already been validated) and simply calculates the appropriate savings.

Taking this kind of approach means that you only have to solve a couple of problems in each method, and you don't have to think about everything at the same time.

**EDIT: Here's the code reorganised as described above**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW04P05 {

    private static final int PACKAGE_1 = 1;
    private static final int PACKAGE_2 = 2;
    private static final int PACKAGE_3 = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int plan = getPlan(input);
        int month = getMonth(input);
        int hours = getHours(input, month);
        calculateSavings(plan, hours);
    }

    private static int getPlan(Scanner input) {
        // packages menu
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[1] Package 1: $15.95 a month for up to 10 hours of service. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("[2] Package 2: $20.95 a month for up to 20 hours of service. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("[3] Package 3: $30.99 per month unlimited access.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter [1 - 3] for select your package: ");

        // get input
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        // input validation
        System.out.println(" ");
        if (choice < 0) {
            exitProgram("The menu choice cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 3]");
        } else if (choice == 0) {
            exitProgram("The menu choice cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 3]");
        } else if (choice > 3) {
            exitProgram("The menu choice must be a value [1 - 3]");
        }
        return choice;
    }

    private static int getMonth(Scanner input) {
        // month menu
        System.out.println("[1] January   [4] April  [7] July       [10] October");
        System.out.println("[2] February  [5] May    [8] August     [11] November");
        System.out.println("[3] March     [6] June   [9] September  [12] December");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter [1 - 12] for select billed month: ");

        // get input
        int month = input.nextInt();

        // input validation
        if (month < 0) {
            exitProgram("The month cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 12]");
        } else if (month == 0) {
            exitProgram("The month cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 12]");
        } else if (month > 12) {
            exitProgram("The month must be a value [1 - 12]");
        }
        return month;
    }

    private static int getHours(Scanner input, int month) {
        // hours menu
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");

        // get input
        int hours = input.nextInt();

        // input validation
        if (hours < 0) {
            exitProgram("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
        }
        if ((month ==  1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && hours > 744) {
            exitProgram("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the month selected.");
        }
        if ((month ==  4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && hours > 720) {
            exitProgram("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 720 on the month selected.");
        }
        if (month == 2 && hours > 672) {
            exitProgram("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on the month selected.");
        }

        return hours;
    }

    private static void calculateSavings(int plan, int hours) {
        double pricePlan1 = calculatePricePlan1(hours);
        double pricePlan2 = calculatePricePlan2(hours);
        double pricePlan3 = 30.99;

        switch(plan) {
            case PACKAGE_1:
                System.out.println(String.format("The cost of your bill is: $%.2f", pricePlan1));
                if (pricePlan1 > pricePlan2) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("On package 2 you could have saved $%.2f", pricePlan1 - pricePlan2));
                }
                if (pricePlan1 > pricePlan3) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("On package 3 you could have saved $%.2f", pricePlan1 - pricePlan3));
                }
                break;

            case PACKAGE_2:
                System.out.println(String.format("The cost of your bill is: $%.2f", pricePlan2));
                if (pricePlan2 > pricePlan3) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("On package 3 you could have saved $%.2f", pricePlan2 - pricePlan3));
                }
                break;

            case PACKAGE_3:
                System.out.println(String.format("The cost of your bill is: $%.2f", pricePlan3));
                break;
        }
    }

    private static double calculatePricePlan1(int hours) {
        if (hours <= 10) {
            return 15.95;
        }

        return 15.95 + ((hours - 10) * 2);
    }


    private static double calculatePricePlan2(int hours) {
        if (hours <= 20) {
            return 20.95;
        }

        return 20.95 + (hours - 20);
    }

    private static void exitProgram(String reason) {
        System.out.println(reason);
        System.out.println("The program will now exit.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Note that each method fits on one 'page' and each can be understood and tested independently. This approach makes it much easier for other developers to understand what the code does (and therefore reduces maintenance cost).

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to run my code. However, I did not use your recommendation because I am not familiarized with that logic yet. As I said this is my fourth-week coding in Java, however, I will keep it in mind in my next codes.

Answer (score 0):

I re-coded and changed some of the sections and I was able to run the code as the problem stated.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW04P05{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
   // create scanner
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 // packages menu
 final String USER_MENU =
  " \n" +
  "[1] Package 1: $15.95 a month for up to 10 hours of service. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.\n" +
  "[2] Package 2: $20.95 a month for up to 20 hours of service. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.\n" +
  "[3] Package 3: $30.99 per month unlimited access.\n" +
  " \n" +
  "Enter [1 - 3] for select your package: ";
 final int PACKAGE_1 = 1;
 final int PACKAGE_2 = 2;
 final int PACKAGE_3 = 3;
 System.out.print(USER_MENU);
 int choice = input.nextInt();
 // input validation
 System.out.println(" ");
 if (choice < 0) {
  System.out.println("The menu choice cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 3]");
  System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
 else if (choice == 0) {
  System.out.println("The menu choice cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 3]");
  System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
 else if (choice > 3) {
  System.out.println("The menu choice must be a value [1 - 3]");
  System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
 // month menu
 System.out.print("[1] January   [4] April  [7] July       [10] October\n");
 System.out.print("[2] February  [5] May    [8] August     [11] November\n");
 System.out.print("[3] March     [6] June   [9] September  [12] December\n");
 System.out.println(" ");
 System.out.print("Enter [1 - 12] for select billed month: ");
 int month = input.nextInt();
 // input validation
 if (month < 0) {
  System.out.println("The month cannot be negative, must be a value [1 - 12]");
  System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
 else if (month == 0) {
 System.out.println("The month cannot be zero, must be a value [1 - 12]");
 System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
 System.exit(1);
 }
 else if (month > 12) {
  System.out.println("The month must be a value [1 - 12]");
  System.out.println("The program will know exit.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
 // declaring variables
 double hours;
 double savings_1;
 double savings_2;
 double total_1;
 double total_2;
 final double total_1d = 15.95;
 final double total_2d = 20.95;
 final double total_3d = 30.99;
 // switch statement
 switch (choice) {
  case PACKAGE_1:
   // if statement for 31d, 30d, & 28d months
   if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 744) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     // computing bill costs and savings
     if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
     }
     else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 20) {
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_1 > 20.95) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2d);
      savings_1 = total_2d - total_1;
      savings_1 = (savings_1 * -1);
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1 );
      System.out.println(" ");
          if (total_1 > 30.99) {
       System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
       savings_2 = total_3d - total_1;
       savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
       savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
       System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
       System.out.println(" ");
       }
         }
     }
     else{
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      total_2 = ((hours - 20) + 20.95);
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
      savings_1 = total_1 - total_2;
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
      savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
     }
    }
   }
   else if (month == 2) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 627) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     // computing bill costs and savings
     if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
     }
     else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 20) {
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_1 > 20.95) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2d);
      savings_1 = total_2d - total_1;
      savings_1 = (savings_1 * -1);
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1 );
      System.out.println(" ");
          if (total_1 > 30.99) {
       System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
       savings_2 = total_3d - total_1;
       savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
       savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
       System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
       System.out.println(" ");
       }
      }
     }
     else{
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      total_2 = ((hours - 20) + 20.95);
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
      savings_1 = total_1 - total_2;
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
      savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
     }
    }
   }
   else {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 720) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 720 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     // computing bill costs and savings
     if (hours < 10 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $15.95");
     }
     else if (hours > 10 && hours <= 20) {
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_1 > 20.95) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2d);
      savings_1 = total_2d - total_1;
      savings_1 = (savings_1 * -1);
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1 );
      System.out.println(" ");
          if (total_1 > 30.99) {
       System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
       savings_2 = total_3d - total_1;
       savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
       savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
       System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
       System.out.println(" ");
       }
         }
     }
     else{
      total_1 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      total_2 = ((hours - 20) + 20.95);
      System.out.println("The cost of package 2 bill is: $" + total_2);
      savings_1 = total_1 - total_2;
      savings_1 = (Math.round(savings_1 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_1);
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $30.99");
      savings_2 = total_1 - total_3d;
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
     }
    }
   }
  break; 
  case PACKAGE_2:
   if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 744) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     // computing bill costs and savings
     if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
     }
     else {
      total_2 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_2 > 30.99) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
      savings_2 = total_3d - total_2;
      savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      }
     }
    }   
   } 
   else if (month == 2) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 672) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     // computing bill costs and savings
     if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
     }
     else {
      total_2 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_2 > 30.99) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
      savings_2 = total_3d - total_2;
      savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      }
     }
    }
   }
   else {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    if (hours > 720) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 720 on the month selected.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     if (hours < 20 && hours >= 1){
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $20.95");
     }
     else {
      total_2 = ((hours - 10) * 2) + 15.95;
      System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $" + total_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      if (total_2 > 30.99) {
      System.out.println("The cost of package 3 bill is: $" + total_3d);
      savings_2 = total_3d - total_2;
      savings_2 = (savings_2 * -1);
      savings_2 = (Math.round(savings_2 * 100)/ 100.0);
      System.out.println("You could have saved: $" + savings_2);
      System.out.println(" ");
      }
     }
    }
   }
  break;
  case PACKAGE_3:
   if ((month == 1) ^ (month == 3) ^ (month == 5) ^ (month == 7) ^ (month == 8) ^ (month == 10) ^ (month == 12)) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    //input validation
    if (hours > 744) {
     System.out.println("ERROR the number of hours cannot be higher than 744 on the selected month.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
    }
   }
   else if (month == 2) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 672) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 672 on the selected month.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
    }
   }  
   else {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the plan package was used: ");
    hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");
    // input validation
    if (hours > 720) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be higher than 720 on the selected month.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else if (hours < 0) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: The number of hours cannot be negative.");
     System.out.println("Now the program will exit.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("The cost of your bill is: $30.99");
    }
   }
 }
 }
}
```